# Demon killer whose brother is his sword. Girl witnesses killing, and is included in the contract

Tags: story-identification, anime, demons

I once watched an anime but I forgot the name.  I only saw the first episode. There was a girl who saw a boy from her school kill a demon or something like that. His sword turned out to be his brother. They kill demons together for an organization. Because she witnessed it, she’s now included in their contract or he has to kill her.

Maybe someone remembers or knows it.

Comment: Hi, H2SOS. More information would help. When was the "once" you watched the anime? Did it seem new then? Etc.

Comment: While I haven't personally seen the anime myself, so I can't really match details, but the first thing comes to mind is [demon slayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_Slayer:_Kimetsu_no_Yaiba)

Comment: @Wondercricket - That's not really the sort of urban fantasy that OP seems to be describing

Comment: @Valorum Eh, it was worth a shot :)

Comment: Hi this may not be accurate but you can go to anime planet and there select tags under the name of 'Action' and 'Demons'. That might help narrow down the options.